# Delphi slow readln() after set memcashed value using TIdTCPClient

Tags: delphi, memcached

I have made a class TmemcacheClass where I can set and get values from memcached.

It's used in a Delphi Webbroker app, where each thread open TmemcacheClass and use it in its life. meaning every thread open TIdTCPClient, and connect it and reuse for every request.

Get value are very speedy like 0 to 1 ms
Set value are also speedy like 1 ms , but to wait for readln after set  takes 47 ms.

Any Idea how to speed this up.

Is the  procedure store() that are very slow waiting for
line:=  tcp.Socket.ReadLn();

Adding hole unit, maybe I could drop the readln after save to speed it up ? 
If I drop readln I guess I need to clear socket since I am reusing same socket.

```
unit unitMemcache;

interface
uses
  system.sysutils,system.classes,system.JSON,idtcpclient,idGlobal;

type

   TmemcacheClass = Class ( Tobject )
    private

    tcp : TIdTCPClient;
    ConnectTimeout : integer;
    Fconnected: Boolean;
    Ferror: String;
    Fcontent: String;
    Flinecounter : Integer;
    procedure Setconnected(const Value: Boolean);
    procedure Seterror(const Value: String);
    procedure reportError(e:string);
    procedure Setcontent(const Value: String);

   public
      constructor create( ip : string ) ;
      destructor Destroy ( ) ; override  ;
      procedure store(Key, Value: string);
      function Lookup(Key: string ): String;
      procedure flush_all;

      procedure Delete(Key: string );

      procedure connect;

      property connected : Boolean read Fconnected write Setconnected;
      property error   : String read Ferror write Seterror;
      property content : String read Fcontent write Setcontent;
   End;

implementation

uses system.dateutils;


{ TmemcacheClass }


procedure TmemcacheClass.connect;
begin
  try
   if not tcp.Connected then
    begin
       tcp.Connect;
       Fconnected:=true;
    end;
  except
     on e: Exception do
    begin
       reportError(e.Message);
       Fconnected:=false;
    end;
  end;

end;

constructor TmemcacheClass.create(ip: string  );
begin
 //  FConnectTimeout := 4000;

  Fconnected:=false;
  tcp := TIdTCPClient.Create;
  tcp.ConnectTimeout :=    1000; // maybe to long  , specially if there is a issue...
  tcp.ReadTimeout    :=    2000;
  tcp.Host := ip;
  tcp.Port := 11211;
  tcp.ReuseSocket := rsTrue;

 end;

procedure TmemcacheClass.Delete(Key: string);
var
  command : String;
  stop    : Boolean;
  line : String;
begin
 connect;  // just in case
   if  Fconnected then
   begin
       command :='delete '+key;
       tcp.Socket.Writeln(command);
       stop:=false;
       repeat
        line:=  tcp.Socket.ReadLn();
        if Line = 'END' then Stop:=true;
        if Line = 'DELETED' then Stop:=true;
        if Line = 'NOT_FOUND' then Stop:=true;
        if (Line = '') and ( not tcp.Socket.ReadLnTimedOut)  then Stop:=true;
        until Stop;
   end;

end;

destructor TmemcacheClass.Destroy;
begin
  tcp.Free;
  inherited;
end;




procedure TmemcacheClass.flush_all;
var
  command : String;
  stop    : Boolean;
  line : String;
begin
 Ferror := '';
 connect;  // just in case
   if  Fconnected then
   begin
       command :='flush_all';
          try
           tcp.Socket.Writeln(command);
          except
             on e: Exception do
            begin
               reportError(e.Message);
               exit;
            end;
          end;

       stop:=false;
       repeat
          try
           line:=  tcp.Socket.ReadLn();
          except
             on e: Exception do
            begin
               reportError(e.Message);
               exit;
            end;
          end;

        if Line = 'OK' then Stop:=true;
        if Line = 'END' then Stop:=true;
        if Line = 'STORED' then Stop:=true;
        if (Line = '') and ( not tcp.Socket.ReadLnTimedOut)  then Stop:=true;
        until Stop;
         if line <> 'STORED' then   line:=  tcp.Socket.ReadLn();
   end;

end;

function TmemcacheClass.Lookup(Key : string): String;
var
   Top : Boolean;
   TopString : String;
   line : String;
   Data : String;
   Stop : Boolean;
   max_loops : Integer;
   topStringValues : Tstringlist;
   command : String;
   size : Integer;

begin
 Ferror := '';
 connect;  // just in case
 result:='';
   if  Fconnected then
   begin

         command :='get '+key;


          try
            tcp.Socket.Writeln(command);
          except
             on e: Exception do
            begin
               reportError(e.Message);
               exit;
               result:='';
            end;
          end;



         Top:=true;
         stop := False;
         data :='';
         max_loops:=0;
         size :=0;
         repeat
           inc(max_loops);
           if top   then
           begin
            tcp.Socket.MaxLineLength:=1700; // default first line  :-)
            try
             TopString:= tcp.Socket.ReadLn();
            except
               on e: Exception do
              begin
                 reportError(e.Message);
                 exit;
                 result:='';
              end;
            end;

            top :=false;
            if TopString = 'END' then Stop:=true;
            if TopString = 'STORED' then Stop:=true;

            if TopString = 'SERVER_ERROR' then
            begin
             Stop:=true;
              reportError('SERVER_ERROR : '+key);
            end;
            if TopString = 'CLIENT_ERROR' then
            begin
             Stop:=true;
             reportError('CLIENT_ERROR : '+key);
            end;


            if (TopString = '') and ( not tcp.Socket.ReadLnTimedOut)  then Stop:=true;
            if stop=false then
            begin
             // Decode top string
             topStringValues := Tstringlist.Create;
             try
               TopString:= StringReplace(TopString,' ','*',[rfReplaceAll]);
               topStringValues.Delimiter:='*';
               topStringValues.DelimitedText:=TopString;
               if topStringValues.Count=4 then
               begin
                 size:=strtointdef( topStringValues[3],1700);
                 tcp.Socket.MaxLineLength:=size+10;  // meassure length add 10 in case  :-) for reading
                end
                 else
                  begin
                   // error with header
                   stop:=true;
                   result:='';
                   data :='';

                  end;
             finally
               topStringValues.Clear;
               topStringValues.Free;
             end
            end;
           end
            else
             begin
                try
                  Line :=  tcp.Socket.ReadLn(); // Can be to long need to check with a stream...
                except
                   on e: Exception do
                  begin
                     reportError(e.Message);
                     exit;
                     result:='';
                  end;
                end;

                if Line = 'END' then Stop:=true;
                if Line = 'STORED' then Stop:=true;
                if (Line = '') and ( not tcp.Socket.ReadLnTimedOut)  then Stop:=true;
                if not stop  then data := data+line;
             end;

             if max_loops > 5000 then
             begin
               stop :=true;
               reportError('max_loops > 500 getting : '+key);
               exit;
             end;
         until stop;

         result:=data;
   end;



end;

procedure TmemcacheClass.reportError(e: string);
begin
 Ferror:=e;
 tcp.Disconnect;
 Fconnected:=false;
 Fcontent:='';

end;

procedure TmemcacheClass.Setconnected(const Value: Boolean);
begin
  Fconnected := Value;
end;

procedure TmemcacheClass.Setcontent(const Value: String);
begin
  Fcontent := Value;
end;

procedure TmemcacheClass.Seterror(const Value: String);
begin
  Ferror := Value;
end;

procedure TmemcacheClass.store(Key, Value: string );
var
  command : String;
  stop    : Boolean;
  line : String;
  start_time         : Extended        ;
  startLabel         : String;


begin
 start_time:= now;
 Ferror := '';
 connect;  // just in case
   if  Fconnected then
   begin
       command :='set '+key+' 0 0 '+length(Value).ToString;
          try
           tcp.Socket.Writeln(command);
           tcp.Socket.Writeln(Value);
          except
             on e: Exception do
            begin
               reportError(e.Message);
               exit;
            end;
          end;

       stop:=false;
       repeat
          try
           line:=  tcp.Socket.ReadLn();
          except
             on e: Exception do
            begin
               reportError(e.Message);
               exit;
            end;
          end;



        if Line = 'END' then Stop:=true;
        if Line = 'STORED' then Stop:=true;
        if (Line = '') and ( not tcp.Socket.ReadLnTimedOut)  then Stop:=true;
        until Stop;
       startLabel:=(MilliSecondsBetween(Now, start_time) ).ToString;
        startLabel:=startLabel;

         if line <> 'STORED' then   line:=  tcp.Socket.ReadLn();
   end;


end;
end.
```

Comment: Are you sure the slowdown is on the client side? Did you sniff the network traffic to see how long the server actually takes to respond?

Comment: Hi Remy, and thanks. I am not sure, but I am doing the test from my local machine and memcached is running on ubuntu vmware. Not sure howto test latency from ubuntu. If I telnet it seems superfast but not able to meassure this  the same way as with Delphi. But it can be memcached is slow in response after storing an item.

Comment: I found this new option  for set in memcavhed "noreply" I will test it        "set test1 0 0 4 noreply"  I will return with result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed the store procedure. Added "noreply" to my command. And comment out the reply readln.

Now it only takes 0 to 1 ms to store new data. Dramatic upgrade in speed after fluch_all is used in memcached, and it need to rebuild.

```
procedure TmemcacheClass.store(Key, Value: string );
var
  command : String;
  stop    : Boolean;
  line : String;
  start_time         : Extended        ;
  startLabel         : String;


begin
 start_time:= now;
 Ferror := '';
 connect;  // just in case
   if  Fconnected then
   begin
       command :='set '+key+' 0 0 '+length(Value).ToString+' noreply';
          try
           tcp.Socket.Writeln(command);
           tcp.Socket.Writeln(Value);
          except
             on e: Exception do
            begin
               reportError(e.Message);
               exit;
            end;
          end;

//       stop:=false;
//       repeat
//          try
//           line:=  tcp.Socket.ReadLn();
//          except
//             on e: Exception do
//            begin
//               reportError(e.Message);
//               exit;
//            end;
//          end;
//
//
//
//        if Line = 'END' then Stop:=true;
//        if Line = 'STORED' then Stop:=true;
//        if (Line = '') and ( not tcp.Socket.ReadLnTimedOut)  then Stop:=true;
//        until Stop;
//       startLabel:=(MilliSecondsBetween(Now, start_time) ).ToString;
//        startLabel:=startLabel;
//
//         if line <> 'STORED' then   line:=  tcp.Socket.ReadLn();
   end;


end;
```